# Help modelling complex shape

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to recreate this [image: Hand drawn object] in blender, and do not know where to start. The main difficult part is the top curved object. I tried extruding some sides of a cylinder and then shrinking them down like this [image: poorly modeled object] but I couldn't get any further. I am relatively new to blender, so all feedback, tips and tricks would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should first draw its profile, here are 2 ways to do it (among many I guess):

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. After you had created the 2D face, how did you extrude it to become a 3D shape, and then how did you smooth the mesh?

Comment: In Edit mode select all your vertices, press E to extrude, then Enter right away, then chose the axis (Y or X). To smooth use a Subdivision Surface modifier, and put some additional edge loops (ctrl R) to sharp the edges.